# r - Replace values in a data.frame column with a different value in the same column based unique ID

Tags: r

I'm trying to loop through a column in a data.frame and replace 9's (invalid) with the next valid value not equal to 9 for each unique id in the data.frame.

I've had no luck with `dplyr`, `lapply`, and I've been searching hard for similar problems to no avail.

```
#dummy data set
id<-c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2)
ind<-c(9,9,9,1,9,9,9,4)
df<-data.frame(id,ind)

#unique doesn't get me what I want
#If I do (i in 1:4) it will work for the first df$id but obviously not the 2nd.
for (i in unique(length(df$id)))
  {
    j=df$ind!=9
    df$ind[i]<-df$ind[j]
  }
```

`unique length(df)` will not work, so I essentially can't get the loop to only apply to the subset of `df$id` values.  I think this will work if I can get past that.  Other non-loop solutions would be appreciated as well.

Comment: So in your example when you say the next valid value not equal to 9, The first rows that contain 9 would be set to 1 and the remaining rows that contain 9 would be set to 4?

Comment: Yes.  For each unique `df$id` it would replace any value of 9 with the first value for that `df$id` that isn't a 9.  So, for the `df$id == 1` the `df$ind` should all equal 1 and for `df$id == 2` ind should all equal 4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use `unique()` you could do something like this. There might be a classier way, but this will do the trick in base R:

```
df <- lapply(unique(df$id), function(x){
  temp <- df[df$id == x,]
  temp[temp$ind == 9, 'ind'] <- temp[which.max(temp$ind != 9), 'ind']
  temp
})
do.call(rbind, df)
```

Comment: This does work, thanks.  Now I just need to go through it and make sure I understand whats going on.  I'm going to keep working on a dplyr and a loop solution as well.

Comment: If this solves your problem then you should mark it as the answer.